# How many steps before the euclidean algorithm terminates?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logarithms, euclidean-algorithm

Before disregarding my question and tagging it as duplicate. Please consider that I have read the similar posts on this, but I couldn't wrap my head around the hints proving the $2\log_2(b)$ part. Maybe I'm not smart enough or maybe I just got started with number theory. I am hoping to get a better hint and how I can relate the "halving" of the remainder every two steps with the value of b and $2\log_2(b)$.

Here are the posts that asked the same question on stackexchange that I have read:

(1)[Show that the number of steps in the Euclidean algorithm is less than $\frac{2\log b}{\log 2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75565/show-that-the-number-of-steps-in-the-euclidean-algorithm-is-less-than-frac2-l?rq=1)

(2)[Show that the Euclidean Algorithm terminates in less than seven times the number of digits in $b$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1957075/show-that-the-euclidean-algorithm-terminates-in-less-than-seven-times-the-number?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**My attempt on first part of the problem**

proof of $r_{i+2} < \frac{1}{2}r_i:$

Let $a - bq_1 = r_1$ s.t. $b=r_0$

$(case 1):$
If $b=r_0< \frac{1}{2}a$ then $q_1 \geq 2$ so that $r_1 < r_0$.
Furthermore, in $r_0 - r_1q_2 = r_2$, since $r_1 \leq \frac{1}{2}r_0$ then  it must be that $q_2 \geq 2$ so that $r_2 < r_1$.
Therefore, $r_2 < r_1 < \frac{1}{2}r_0$ or $r_{i+2}<r_{i+1}< \frac{1}{2}r_i$ or simply $r_{i+2}<\frac{1}{2}r_i$.

$(case 2):$
If $b=r_0> \frac{1}{2}a$ then $ a- r_0q_1 = r_1$ such that $r_1 < \frac{1}{2}a$ and $r_1 < r_0$ and $q_1=1$

$(subcase 2.1):$ If $r_1 > \frac{1}{2}r_0$ then definitely, $r_2 < \frac{1}{2}r_0$ or $r_{i+2}<\frac{1}{2}r_i$

$(subcase 2.2)$ If $r_1 < \frac{1}{2}r_0$ then $q_2 \geq 2$ so that $r_2 < r_1$.
Therefore, $r_2<r_1< \frac{1}{2}r_0$ or $r_{i+2}<r_{i+1}< \frac{1}{2}r_i$

From here, I am struggling to apply logarithms to show the final step.

Comment: The algorithm terminates when $r=0$. You start with $r=b$, and you've just seen that every two steps, $r$ is at least halved. So how many halvings can $b$ take before it drops below $1$ (and hence must be $0$)?

Comment: I'm thinking along the lines of the expression $b(\frac{1}{2})^n$, but I don't think it should be equated to 0...?

Comment: i think $n$ becomes the number of "2 steps"? so must it be $b(\frac{1}{2})^{2n}$?

Comment: Even though $b(\frac{1}{2})^n$ is usually rational rather than an integer, you know that after $2n$ steps, the value of $r$ will fall below $b(\frac{1}{2})^n$. If after enough steps you have $b(\frac{1}{2})^n<1$, then you must have $r=0$ because it is the only integer value still possible, and the algorithm terminates.

Comment: i think. I've got it! thanks!